# Getting elevation profile graphs along parallel interpolate lines using ArcGIS 3D Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, elevation, 3d-analyst, profile

I'm new to ArcGIS. I have used "Interpolate Line" tool in the 3D Analyst Toolbox to get an elevation profile graph.

1. How can I create several parallel interpolate lines, maybe with specific distance interval, and get their elevation profile graphs?
2. How can I get the elevation profile graphs from different DEM at exactly the same location?

There's no way that I can change the layer and redraw the same line manually.

Comment: Best to limit a question to one question to only one question. Rather ask two and link them together in text.

Comment: If you have few lines, stored as feature class,select one on editing session, copy parallel etc. Use interpolate shape from 3d to convert to 3d lines. Select each line and use 3d profile on as many as you want.

Answer (score 1):

The method of interpolating the line using the 3D Toolbar produces a graphic and assigns the z elevation to that specific graphic.

You need to interpolate new lines for different profiles.

Comment: Thank you!  How can I get several parallel lines and get their elevation profile graphs?

Comment: Offhand I am not aware of a dedicated cross section tool other than the toolbar in the 3D analyst. You could interpolate numerous lines and repeat the cross section tool. Or use the ArcHydro AH Profile Toolbar.